# Holt Winters initialization using backcasting like SPSS

Tags: time-series, spss, algorithms, exponential-distribution, smoothing

I'm trying to figure out how SPSS is initializing the multiplicative Holt Winters exponential smoothing model using backcasting. Thankfully IBM roughly [described](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v21r0m0/topic/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_tsmodel_models_exsmooth_estimation_initialization.htm) their way of doing so .. very roughly.

Assuming a seasonal period of 3 and 3 seasons (9 observations) for the sake of simplicity. As far as I understand they fit lines for all corresponding observations of all seasons with intercept.

Fitting observations 1,4,7 with intercept $µ_1$ and slope $β_1$ .. fitting observations 2,5,8 with intercept $µ_2$ and slope $β_2$ .. and so on.

So the initial trend is the average of all slopes. But how exactly are the seasonal indices computed? And isn't the intercept mostly the first observation on a regression line, is it?? (e.g. observation 1 for the first line)

EDIT: I guess it will help me a lot if I know more about how backcasting is performed in general. All I found in literature is that the time series is reversed and smoothed values are generated for the season before $t_1$. But how do I get the initial values used for forecasting when I only have compound backcasts?

Comment: I managed to compute the multiplicative indices since it's simply the division of a vector by a scalar. What now bothers me is that these indices are too small by a factor of 10 .. but afterwards they appear to be reasonable seasonal initial indices.

Comment: The link just sends me to the a portal front page.

Comment: Does the SPSS algorithms book help? ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/24.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf