# How to set initial values for Holt-Winters backcasting?

Tags: time-series, smoothing, exponential-smoothing

I'm trying to figure out how to set initial seasonal values for backcasting of the multiplicative Holt Winters. As pointed out in this thread: [Holt Winters initialization using backcasting like SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66055/holt-winters-initialization-using-backcasting-like-spss), you can set:
$$
{\rm Seasonal\ Index}_i = \frac{m_i + b_i}{\sum(m_i + b_i)}.
$$
This method produces the same results as SAS and SPSS when $m_i + b_i > 0$. But what should be done when $m_i + b_i < 0$?